# Socratic badge bug

Tags: support, badges

The site just awarded me the [socratic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/409/socratic) badge twice, separated only by a 1 hour interval. This seems indicative of a bug to me.

Comment: I am guessing this has to do with the fact that your original user is merged with a newer user.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, it was?

Comment: Also, note that you were already awarded this badge quite some time ago!

Comment: goblin, yes, your current user number is 42339 but it used to be 18921.

Comment: Tim also got it twice...

Comment: @CareBear: But Tim is an Enchanter. So it's not a big surprise there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug, but a change of the behavior of the badge.

1. Originally, [Jon Ericson proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/) that Socratic should be awarded multiple times: i.e., 3 badges for 300 qualifying  asking days.
2. Debate ensued, and SE "decided to hold off on multiple awards for now."
3. Today they enabled multiple awards of Socratic badge, resulting in several users [receiving additional badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/409/socratic). As an extreme example, [Yoichi Oishi](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi?tab=activity) from English.SE  got four copies of the badge today, at irregular intervals.

I guess the gaps between badge awards have to do with how the script is written: it ran through the database looking for users with 200+ good asking days and gave them a second badge, then ran through 300+ days and gave third badge, etc.

Comment: Then maybe they should change Fanatic to multiple awards too; then I can get another 14 gold badges on main (and 10 more on meta). :P